# How to remove the action of a menu.xml item?

Tags: magento2, overrides, action, menu.xml

I have a menu.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Xtento_TrackingImport::menu" action="Xtento_TrackingImport/index/index" title="Some title" module="Xtento_TrackingImport" sortOrder="101" parent="Magento_Sales::sales" resource="Third_Party::menu"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

I want to remove the 'action' in it.
I've try some thing like this in my override menu.xml file :

```
<update id="Xtento_TrackingImport::menu"/>
```

And

```
<update id="Xtento_TrackingImport::menu" action=""/>
```

And also

```
<update id="Xtento_TrackingImport::menu" action="#"/>
```

But none of them work.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: would it be because you are trying it with the update element?

Comment: thanks, but if i don't update, then how to make this work?

Comment: what is your main goal on this? are you trying to override your third-party menu.xml and remove the action only for that specific menu or are you trying to implement your own menu without an action?

Comment: i'm just trying to remove the action from a item from menu.xml, i don't wanna add a new item at all. Thanks.

Comment: then try like `<add id="Xtento_TrackingImport::menu" action=""/>`

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work.

Comment: it throw an error: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid Document Element 'add', attribute 'action': [facet 'pattern'] The value '' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9/_]{3,}'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91891/discussion-between-magefms-and-fudu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using update tag in menu.xml, what you can do is create a plugin of menu file in your custom module.

So in your custom module, make following changes.

> [Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Config">
    <plugin name="custom_override_meu_action" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Config" />
</type>
```

> [Vendor][Module]\Plugin\Config.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin;

class Config
{
    public function afterGetMenu($subject, $result)
    {
        $result->get('Xtento_TrackingImport::menu')->setAction(null);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: worked. thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
       <update id="Xtento_TrackingImport::menu" action="#"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Should work.

But you have to check that your menu`menu.xml` code should run after  `<add id="Xtento_TrackingImport::menu"...`

You have to create a new module. this should depend on `Xtento_TrackingImport`

using  `<depends><Xtento_TrackingImport/></depends>`

and the new module's menu you have to rewrite **the update menu code**.

Comment: Wait, so its still have action? i want to make it without action, the reason i do that because the menu will become like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2BpO.jpg you see the "tracking import" down there? i want it to become look like "Sales Export"
the only way to do that is remove the action.
Right now it have action, so it become that <a href="trackingimport/index/index">